# Why Use IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

I have a web application that needs to be very secure.  I have read the IdentyServer4 overview.  I don't understand under what circumstances I would need to use it.  I would appreciate it if anyone could clarify.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not only is asking for opinion on a product not allowed on SO but your question is about a server program which is also off topic here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm not asking for an opinion.  I'm asking for clarification.  This is a legit tag.

Comment: "very secure" is a big topic. Access control is only one aspect of that, which is what Identity Server brings to the party.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for
>   ASP.NET Core

It gives you the power of single sign on for all your applications. Single centralized server which can verify your client applications, Issue access tokens for APIs for various types of clients, you can configure the options according to your requirements.

identity server will give you secure login and API access protection - you will be accessing the api resources through secure token, and Identity server is build upon openID connect and oauth2.0 which will manage the tokens for you.

Not to forget, all the login code and logic(which is required for almost all the web apps today) has been tested hundred times and improved over time. This makes it almost bug free and much more reliable than writing the same thing yourself!